# Git remote tracking branch diverged from local branch with identical commits with different SHAs

Tags: git

Here is my git repo's current state (as visualised in GitX).

[image: Diverged git history]

The '34e...' and 'c3d...' commits (the 'Implemented a global...' commented ones) are IDENTICAL. I confirmed this with git diff, and they even have identical commit times! The only difference is their SHAs.

I have no idea how I got my repo into this state. While I am no git pro, I have been using it for a while now and have become very comfortable with all the basics. This has occurred out of the blue, and I wasn't experimenting with any git features or workflows that I hadn't used before, so I am rather confused.

No one else has committed anything to the remote, so I can change history there, but a solution not involving that would be better.

I could just do the normal merge or rebase of master and origin/master, but I am uncomfortable with that as the history will then show 2 identical commits.

Is it possible to checkout origin/master and then rebase all the commits starting at 'a4a...' onto origin/master, and then switch master to this new HEAD? (basically leaving the 'c3d...' commit hanging by itself, which doesnt matter as its the dupe)

1) So whats the preferred way to fix this?
2) Any ideas how this happened? Anyone else seen it before?

EDIT:
**git diff c3db784817 34e1ab666a**: outputted nothing.

**git reflog master**:

> Bender:mt-d-styles tyson$ git reflog master
>   9579294 master@{0}: commit: Added debug only console printing to test image view
>   1155228 master@{1}: commit: Added new marker interface that custom cells can imp
>   a4ab788 master@{2}: commit: Added a new StyledRootElement that automatically app
>   c3db784 master@{3}: commit: Implemented a global technique for styling all exist
>   34e1ab6 master@{4}: commit: Implemented a global technique for styling all exist
>   8519fb1 master@{5}: commit: Extended the remove method to give callers access to
>   30aeee6 master@{6}: commit: Added a new factory method based Side Swipe View con

**git reflog origin/master**:

> Bender:mt-d-styles tyson$ git reflog origin/master
>   34e1ab6 refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: update by push
>   8519fb1 refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}: update by push
>   495e0ef refs/remotes/origin/master@{2}: update by push
>   c5fec81 refs/remotes/origin/master@{3}: update by push
>   cba1e0f refs/remotes/origin/master@{4}: update by push
>   9ee1ffb refs/remotes/origin/master@{5}: update by push
>   68ee429 refs/remotes/origin/master@{6}: update by push
>   0e2d199 refs/remotes/origin/master@{7}: update by push
>   8a4de84 refs/remotes/origin/master@{8}: update by push

EDIT 2:
**git log --format=raw --decorate --graph --all**:

```
*  commit c3db7848171f396c5a595a35dd6b609c119f9e84 
| tree 998e9749546d05178798c8a462d3eff02a111f4c 
| parent 8519fb17e77b8ae865e071772ae652316df8822a 
| author Tyson <tyson> 1364529327 +0800 
| committer Tyson <tyson> 1364539365 +0800 
|  
|     Implemented a global technique for styling all existing MT.D element backg 
|  


| * commit 34e1ab666a81dde7582ee9e31bfa961420d38f55 (origin/master) 
|/  tree 38f9e0c3d936c702fdcd18d215a2f0a88280893b 
|   parent 8519fb17e77b8ae865e071772ae652316df8822a 
|   author Tyson <tyson> 1364529327 +0800 
|   committer Tyson <tyson> 1364529327 +0800 
|    
|      Implemented a global technique for styling all existing MT.D element bac 
|
```

Comment: What does `git diff c3d784 34e1ab` show?

Comment: And also `git reflog master` `git reflog origin/master` output please.

Comment: @kan See edits in question.

Comment: This does look like you amended your commit. But not with the command-line client.

Comment: @Chronial Yep, I do quite often use amend from within GitX. Still doesn't explain why `git diff` shows no differences between the two. Out of curiosity, what is it about the reflog output that makes it look like I amended?

Comment: I extended my answer to answer that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Cause**:
You probably did some history rewriting. If the commits where exactly identical, the SHA would automatically be the same. What you see in you UI is not the commit date, but the author date. Run `git log --format=raw --decorate ̵-graph --all` to get more details. I guess you will see that the commit date of your local version is a later date. That is caused by history rewriting, usually amending or rebasing.

**The Solution**:
If you know how to go back, you could just try pulling with rebase – if the commits really are identical, git *should* realize this and only add one commit. If you don’t know how to go back, just rebase `master` onto `origin/master`, cutting at c3db784817:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master c3db784817 master
```

---

### @Your question in the comments:

How I know you amended from the reflog:

```
c3db784 master@{3}: commit: Implemented a global technique for styling all exist
34e1ab6 master@{4}: commit: Implemented a global technique for styling all exist
```

Your master branch was at `34e1ab6`, after you created a commit. Then you pushed this commit. Then your master branch moved to `c3db784` – a commit with the same message, and your git client says the reason for this was `commit`. Since there was no branch head movement in between, this smells a lot like an amend. The command line client would say `commit (amend)` though.

And your log tells me that you did the first commit at unix time `1364529327` (2013-03-28 20:55:27) and then amended it at unix time `1364539365` (2013-03-28 23:42:45). (And that you probably live in the US ;)

Comment: Your right! See my 2nd edit above, with the `git log` output - different 'committer' times. And I do quite often use the amend feature. But so does this mean I made a commit, pushed it, and then amended, thereby only amending the local commit?

Comment: yes, you will always only amend local commits. Any you *should* never rewrite (=amend) published history. And amends will `always` rewrite, even if you changed nothing, because the commit time changes – as you saw.

Comment: Hmmm... I swear I have tried to do this in the past (amending after pushing) and git stopped me, or at least warned me. Perhaps it's GitX's amend that doesn't warn. Anyway, the `rebase --onto` using the SHA of the commit to create the patch from was exactly what I was looking for! Worked a treat! Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand why tree ids `998e974` and `38f9e0c` are different, but `diff` doesn't show anything. And why reflog doesn't have `(amend)`. Is it just GitX bug?

Comment: BTW, `git rebase origin/master` would be enough to heal such history, the `--onto` thing is not necessary.

Comment: @kan: I said that as the first sentence in my reply. But from my experience, that feature (patch ids) does not always work correctly. I think the missing `(amend)` is a GitX bug – if you want to call it that. The different trees are indeed interesting. @Tyson: care to grab `git cat-file -p **SHA**` and investigate?